# Making Independent Elements Appear on Seperate Divs with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an extra text-box appear on button press - as I have many separate divs, each one should open its own little box with its own unique text. Right now it only opens the first one as they all share the same ID.

Code example of the current situation:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("infoTab");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    padding-bottom: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background: blue;
    padding: 100px;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.wrapper .item {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper .item #infoTab {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: white;
    position:relative;
    top: 0;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper"> 
<div class="item">
  <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Info</button>
  <p>text 1.1</p>
  <div id="infoTab" style="display:none;">
    <p>text 2.1</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Info</button>
  <p>text 1.2</p>
  <div id="infoTab" style="display:none;">
    <p>text 2.2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/Gregiboi/pen/WNJJzbd)

From what I've read I understand exactly WHY it's happening, but I'm clueless on how to make it work with multiple Divs. Sadly my search for the answer was unsuccessful (might be due to my bad terminology).

Comment: never use the same id for 2 elements

Comment: @ATP Yes I'm aware that's a big no-no thing to do. I'd gladly make unique IDs for each div (say "tab1", "tab2", etc.), but sadly I don't know how to implement it with JS and just coping the same JS code for each ID seems silly.

Comment: Explained in the answer. BTW there is an element exactly for this purpose [(<details>)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) (you can customize the button and removing the default arrow as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be to pass the button as parameter to `myFunction()` (using `this` keyword) , get the button parent, find it's  `infoTab` child (using `querySelector(".infoTab")` ) when `infoTab` is a class and not an id, and toggling it's `display`:

```js
function myFunction(button) {
    var parent = button.parentNode; //parent of button. (<div class="item">)

    var x = parent.querySelector(".infoTab");//returns the fisrt child of parent which has infoTab class
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    padding-bottom: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background: blue;
    padding: 100px;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.wrapper .item {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper .item .infoTab {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: white;
    position:relative;
    top: 0;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper"> 
<div class="item">
  <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">Info</button>
  <p>text 1.1</p>
  <div class="infoTab" style="display:none;">
    <p>text 2.1</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">Info</button>
  <p>text 1.2</p>
  <div class="infoTab" style="display:none;">
    <p>text 2.2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup, this is exactly what I was looking for - thank you so much! And thanks for the tip on <details>. While it's not exactly what I need here, it will be useful with other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign multiple elements the same id in javascript, instead, use name:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByName("infoTab");
    for (element of x){
      if (element.style.display === "none") {
        element.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        element.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    padding-bottom: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background: blue;
    padding: 100px;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.wrapper .item {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper .item [name=infoTab] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: white;
    position:relative;
    top: 0;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper"> 
<div class="item">
  <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Info</button>
  <p>text 1.1</p>
  <div name="infoTab" style="display:none;">
    <p>text 2.1</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Info</button>
  <p>text 1.2</p>
  <div name="infoTab" style="display:none;">
    <p>text 2.2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```